# SQL Server query that returns data between two date times with format 01/07/2020 01:01:01 a. m

Tags: sql-server

I've been having problems with a query that returns data between two date times, the query that I'm trying to fix is this one

```
pay.date BETWEEN '01/06/2020 00:28:46 a. m.' AND '01/06/2020 10:38:45 a. m.'
```

That query does not detect the a. m. part and if I have a payment at 10 am and 10 pm it will detect both payments as the t. t. part is not detected, I've been searching for a while now with no luck, thanks in advance :)

Comment: It sounds like it's doing an alphabetic comparison. Is `pay.date` even an actual date? A few simple string `replace()` calls might be all you need though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the filtering by an actual `datetime` type:

```
cast(replace(replace(pay.date, ' a. m.', 'am'), ' p. m.', 'pm') as datetime)
```

It might be better to use `convert()` so you can specify the proper format. If you can't supply the date literals in a readily convertible format then do a similar replace and cast on those too.

Comment: looks like it works, you are amazing i'll do more tests tomorow with more data but on the ones i did it filters with am/pm, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a literal format that is unambiguous and not dependent on runtime or connection settings. More info in [Tibor's discussion](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes).

In this case:

```
where pay.date between '20200601 00:28:46' and '20200601 10:38:45'
```

Notice that I assume June, not January - adjust as needed. Between is inclusive and be certain that you understand the limitations of the datatype for `pay.date`. If datetime, the values are accurate to 3ms. Verify that your data is consistent with your assumption about accuracy to seconds.

Comment: the problem is that the database is currently about 3,000 entries right now and every one of them is in that format, at the time we made the system the money report was daily (english is not my first language so i dont know the exact word for it), and due to some requests we would like to make it am-pm and fixing the database would be a little hard, its not mandatory to make that report but it would be interesting fixing that problem and if its not possible with a query we'll try via c# once we load the data into it, thanks for your response :).